# Prove $\lim_{x\to\infty}{e^{-1\over x^2}\over x}=0$ Wrong demonstration

Tags: calculus

Ok guys I was working on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949623/proof-that-the-limit-of-e-1-x2-x-0-as-x-approaches-zero#1949623) but it seems I got it wrong. Since the post has been flagged as duplicate and I don't have enough rep to post comments yet, please help me find where I did something wrong :

For reference, the original post was about proving $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$

> Let's note $f(x) = {e^{-1\over x^2}\over x}$ and $g(x) = ln(f(x))= -\left(1\over{x^2.ln(x)} \right)$
>
> We can see that $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = 0$ wich is to say $\lim_{x\to\infty} ln(f(x)) = 0$
>
> Which is $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 1$

Comment: What do you mean by "help me find where I did something wrong"?  Are you asking about why you couldn't get the correct answer to your math question, or are you asking about why your original post was closed?

Comment: your $g(x)$ is not correct. you must have $\frac{-1}{x^2}-ln(x)$

Comment: Omnom the original post was not mine, I was trying to help the author and got it wrong. Abdallah you're absolutly right that's where I did a mistake. Thanks for the help guys =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for all $x$, $0\le e^{-1/x^2}\le 1$.  Thus, given $\epsilon>0$, we have

$$\left|\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}\right|\le \frac1x<\epsilon$$

whenever $x>1/\epsilon$.  And we are done.

Comment: This is very clean proof, congratulation. Although my post was more about what I did wrong in my demonstration ( I misapplied $ln()$ ).